# After crash google-chrome start in window mode

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-chrome, xvfb, python-webbrowser

I have some python script whitch I start on server **debian 9** from difrent user, whitch i created by command `useradd`
in `xvfb` session:

```
su -l username -c 'xvfb-run -a --server-args="-screen 0 1240x1024x24" python /path/to/python_script.py'
```

in scrip i start google-chrome and do some actions for test:

```
import webbrowser
controller = webbrowser.get('google-chrome').open('site_url')
...
```

But after crash in some users `google-chrome` begin started in window mode (not full screen) see screenshot:

[image]

How can i fix it by using python?
I already try to send `ALTLEFT + F10 etc.` by `pyautogui` :

```
impotr pyautogui
pyautogui.hotkey('altleft', 'f10') - no result
```

also try:

```
pyautogui.hotkey('f11') - no result
```

and start `chrome-browser` with key `--kiosk`:

```
webbrowser.get('/usr/bin/google-chrome --kiosk') - got exception
```

**Update:**
Exception is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/path/to/python_script.py", line 519, in
<module>youtube_clicker.main()
File "/path/to/python_script.py", line 450, in main
self.controller.open_new("https://site.url")
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/webbrowser.py", line 151, in open_new
return self.open(url, 1)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/webbrowser.py", line 275, in open
success = self._invoke(args, True, autoraise)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/webbrowser.py", line 238, in _invoke
stderr=inout, preexec_fn=setsid)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1024, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: What exception did you get?

Comment: Pls see update.

Comment: The ``webbrowser`` module docs say, the parameter to get is a string indicating the browser (in the docs not even a path). Maybe you should try the ``subprocess`` module instead, there you can pass parameters to the program.

Comment: Ok, thanks for reply